# regular expression to strip attributes and values from html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi Guys I'm very new to regex, can you help me with this.

I have a string like this `"<input attribute='value' >"` where `attribute='value'` could be anything and  I want to get do a `preg_replace` to get just `<input />`

How do I specify a wildcard to replace any number of any characters in a srting?

like this? `preg_replace("/<input.*>/",$replacement,$string);`

Many thanks

Answer (score 10):

What you have:

```
.*
```

will match "any character, and as many as possible.

what you *mean* is

```
[^>]+
```

which translates to "any character, thats not a ">", and there must be at least one

or altertaively,

```
.*?
```

which means
"any character, but only enough to make this rule work"

## BUT DONT

Parsing HTML with regexps is **Bad**

use any of the existing html parsers, DOM librarys, anything, Just NOT NAïVE  REGEX

For example:

```
 <foo attr=">">
```

Will get grabbed wrongly by regex as

```
'<foo attr=" ' with following text of '">'
```

Which will lead you to this regex:

```
 `<[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+=['"][^"']['"])*)>  etc etc
```

at which point you'll discover this lovely gem:

```
 <foo attr="'>\'\"">
```

and your head will explode.

( the syntax highlighter verifies my point, and incorrectly matches thinking i've ended the tag. )

Comment: The concept with "as many as possible" vs. "just enough" is called "greediness" in most documentation.

Comment: @John: yeah, i know, but this guys obviously green on those terms ;)

Comment: You were right on the head explosion part... speaking from experience.

Comment: How do you come to think such a monstrosity as "<foo attr='>'>" was even *possible* in HTML? I know you talk about XSS, but I guess we are not looking at a "How do I sanitize broken user input?" question here. Allowing users to input HTML is a big WTF in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Some people were close... but not 100%:

This:

```
preg_replace("<input[^>]*>", $replacement, $string);
```

should be this:

```
preg_replace("<input[^>]*?>", $replacement, $string);
```

You don't want that to be a greedy match.

Comment: Greediness is irrelevant here, as the use of [^>]* instead of .* will cause it to match all non-> characters until a > is found and the longest (greedy) and shortest (non-greedy) runs of non-> characters followed by a > will be identical in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("<input[^>]*>", $replacement, $string); 
// [^>] means "any character except the greater than symbol / right tag bracket"
```

This is really *basic* stuff, you should [catch up with some reading](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html). :-)

Comment: This almost works, but it fails on attributes which have a '>' in the value, e.g. <input attr="3>2">.

Comment: @Adam: which is *exactly* why you shouldn't use Regex to parse html.

Comment: Funnily, it looks like allowing > in attributes values was made only to make a point against using regexes on HTML (I never saw it used in real life). But that's a good point.

Comment: @PHiLho,  hopefully not used in real life, but its one of the ways people create code for XSS purposes. And that gets ugly fast.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that but there are no '>' characters in attribute values. Never. If there are in *your* HTML, you've got a completely different problem at your hands.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is *basic* stuff by any stretch of the imagination. Making sure you are matching HTML properly is a fairly difficult thing to achieve, especially when you start trying to match nested tags.

Comment: He did not say anything about nested tags. His question was quite straight-forward, and the regex that does what he wants really *is* basic.

Comment: You are right - '>' character inside attributes is not valid, but most popular browser can parse it correctly in most cases (if attribute value is properly quoted). Real world code sample with '>' inside attribute value: <input ... onkeypress="if (this.length > 10) return false;">

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you have the code:

```
preg_replace("/<input.*>/",$replacement,$string);
```

and you want us to tell you what you should use for $replacement to delete what was matched by .*

You have to go about this the other way around.  Use capturing groups to capture what you want to keep, and reinsert that into the replacement.  E.g.:

```
preg_replace("/(<input).*(>)/","$1$2",$string);
```

Of course, you don't really need capturing groups here, as you're only reinserting literal text.  Bet the above shows the technique, in case you want to do this in a situation where the tag can vary.  This is a better solution:

```
preg_replace("/<input [^>]*>/","<input />",$string);
```

The negated character class is more specific than the dot.  This regex will work if there are two HTML tags in the string.  Your original regex won't.